# MySQL ALTER TABLE sort columns alphabetically

Tags: mysql, database, alter-table

I am maintaining a legacy application with MySQL database with most of the tables having 20+ columns and few have 100+. To make the it friendlier I am trying to alter all the tables to arrange all the columns sorted alphabetically.

What would be the appropriate `ALTER TABLE` queries ?

Comment: What with `INSERT INTO tab VALUES` when you change the order? Are you sure your legacy app everywhere specifies columns?

Comment: I would not do that...

Comment: There's no point in modifying the order of the columns... you can specify the order of the columns every time you select from the table (`select field_a, field_b, ... from your_table`) or when you insert data into it (`insert into your_table (field_a, field_b, ...) values (...), (...), ...`)

Comment: Though it is a legacy app, It's written in Django with no raw sql queries. Does this change your opinion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way for changing column order in a mysql table. However, you can create a new table with the columns in your order, using for example:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g FROM old_table_name
```

This way, your newly created table will have columns in your defined order, and you can drop the old table and rename the newtable to old name.

In order to create the above mentioned query, you just need to get column names from your old table and sort them, to do that programatically you can use something like this:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='database_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'old_table_name' 
ORDER BY column_name
```